# codegen matlab to c++ :- Problems when attempting to build a c++ based .exe rather than c?

Tags: c++, c, matlab, matlab-coder, codegen

I am having a few problems with using codegen (via the gui interface).

I have successfully built a very simple c based .exe program based on the following two files.

coderand.m

```
function r = coderand() %#codegen
r = rand();
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "coderand.h"
int main()
{
  printf("coderand=%g\n", coderand());
  return 0;
}
```

If I now try and change out main.c for the same code in a main.cpp,

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "coderand.h"

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("coderand=%g\n", coderand());
}
```

I get the following compile errors.

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl coderand(void)" (?coderand@@YANXZ) referenced in function _main 25 F:\CoderTest\coderand.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Any help much appreciated.

Edit:- Solved by myself...

For those suffering the same problem...

Coder -> More Settings -> All Settings -> Advanced -> Language..change C to C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ can call C functions without difficulty, you just have to let the compiler know that the C calling convention applies to this function, like so:

```
extern "C" {
#  include "coderand.h"
}
```

Comment: I am aware of that, but I think you may have misunderstood the specific question. I have found the solution myself...hidden away deep in the matlab settings is a tiny box which says C or C++....Thanks anyway

Comment: @oracle3001: Did you try my answer?  It will solve the unresolved external error, because it will look for a function named according to the C conventions and not C++ conventions.  The C++ naming convention mangles the name to include parameter types, the C convention does not.